# Purifying cysteine containing peptides

Tags: biochemistry, chemical-biology, proteins, amino-acids

I would like to purify my peptide having cysteine residue by using HPLC. It is known that thiol containing peptides undergo oxidation and form disulfide linkages. In order to prevent it I used proper cocktail solution during cleavage from the resin. However, I am still worried what if my peptide undergo oxidation during HPLC purification? How can I prevent it?

I searched in research gate, but I couldn't find suitable answers.

Comment: One way is to add reducing agent to the running buffer. I don't know of another way.

Comment: What reducing agent I can use? Any experience?

Comment: This might be useful as a comparison: http://agscientific.com/blog/2019/04/side-by-side-comparison-dtt-vs-tcep-preferred-reducing-reagents/ Also, I recommend searching a little more, it's not an uncommon problem.

Comment: Most HPLCs have degassers, so oxygen tension in the apparatus should be low and oxidation should be minimal.  You can inject from a TCEP (or DTT or BME)-containing _sample_, as recommended by @CuriousTree, and add these same agents to your fraction collector's tubes ahead of time, but you shouldn't need to add them to you chromatography buffers.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know about HPLC column tolerance to various reducing agents, this would need to be checked. However, in biochemistry we routinely add reducing agents to avoid disulphide-bridge formation in the proteins.

Overall there are three main reducing agents used, to avoid this problem. The choice of which one to use depends on your needs. They include:

- [TCEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCEP): Considered the golden standard, it is relatively odourless compared to the other reducing agents. Once you have dissolved it, it should also remain very stable over time. Typically used at a 0.4 mM concentration.
- [DTT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithiothreitol): Cheaper than TCEP, although I have heard that it is not as stable over time
- [2-Mercaptoethano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-Mercaptoethanol)l: The absolute cheapest, [stinks like crazy](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/64662/should-%CE%B2-mercaptoethanol-and-anything-that-touches-it-be-handled-only-under-fume). Typically to a final of 5 mM.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than worry about reducing agents in the HPLC column, why not oxidize your cysteines with [Ellman's Reagent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellman%27s_reagent) and reduce them after purification?

As long as you use an excess of Ellman's Reagent, it should completely oxidize the thiols and prevent disulfide bond formation.